# Promoting certain SQL rows with PHP

Tags: php, sql

Is there a way of returning a SQL table with id's that are contained in an array.

So the array ($UserFavs) contains values of 45,65,32 and these relate to a column in the DB called id, when selecting all rows from the table I would like any rows in the $UserFavs array to be displayed first.

I tried the following but didn't work:

```
"SELECT * FROM keeper order by id WHERE `id` IN (' . implode(',', array_map('intval', $UserFavs)) . ')';"
```

But this didn't work.

It is Key that all rows are returned but the rows in the array appear first.

Thanks,
B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM keeper ORDER by CASE WHEN `id` IN (...) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END"
```

Answer (score 1):

"display order" is not something you should use queries for, as this is a presentation detail.

Instead, you can fetch the individual records separately, appending them to an array that will store items in "display order"; and then filter the other records from the database using `NOT IN` and append these rows to your display ordered array.

Since arrays default to [`FIFO`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO), when you display the records they will be iterated over in the order they were added to the array.

Comment: Thanks @Burhan - do you have an example?